# Deselect row of a UITableViewController's UITableView when embedded in a PageViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

Normally when a `UITableViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, is returned to from it's detail screen the previously selected row's highlight fades away.

I am trying to replicate this behaviour when a `UITableViewController` is loaded by a `UIPageViewController`, but have been unsuccessful so far.

To be clear, my hierarchy when in the detail screen is: `UINavigationController`>`UIPageViewController`>`UITableViewController`>`DetailController`

Putting the `deselectRow:atIndexPath:` table view method in the `viewDidAppear` of the `UITableViewController` as `viewDidAppear` is not called. Putting it in the same method, but of the `UIPageViewController` works, but there is a noticeable delay before the selection fades away.

Has anyone managed to get this to work properly?

Comment: having the same issue...will answer when fixed (next 30 min)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to `UITableView` or `UITableViewController` here

> I am trying to replicate this behaviour when a
>   **UITableViewController** is loaded by a UINavigationController, but have been unsuccessful so far.

If its a `UITableViewController`, then it has this `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property which does it for you. And it defaults to `true`.

Comment: The problem is that's not being called in this case. I'll update my question with the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but this works for me...

Table View Controller code changes:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.reloadData()   //added this
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "appCell") as! AppTableViewCell
    cell.app = apps[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.reset()    //added this
    return cell
}
```

Table View Cell code changes:

```
//added this method
func reset() {
    shortcutTypesTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Basically, I'm reloading the whole top table view, and in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` I'm telling each cell to reset, which force's each cell's table view to also reload.

My app doesn't have much overhead when loading this table view (at least yet) so I don't notice a performance difference. However, I would not call this solution "ideal" for performance.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` never gets called for me